# SSIS: Is it possible setting a password for a ssis package just like we did for dts legacy packages?

Tags: ssis, passwords, package

Is it possible setting a password for a ssis package just like we did for dts lagacy packages?  I've created a new ssis package but do not know how to set a password for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  It's called the package [ProtectionLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx).  By default, it's set to encrypt only sensitive information so that only your account can read/use it.  But you can change it to use a password.

Answer (score 1):

Your better off using [package configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx), that way it is easier to configure any changes for a test environment. We store all our connection details in these configuration files and have two sets - one for test, one for production.